# I can't figure out why my textbox isn't firing my OnClick c# function in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and I can't figure out why my onClick function isn't firing.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnClick="TextBox1_OnClick"></asp:TextBox>
```

I then have a c# function that I need to run when the textbox is clicked:

```
protected void TextBox1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: am I doing this right and it's some other problem that I'm running into? because I was able to get a button to run an OnClick event

Comment: Could you please verify that you have bind correct code behind class with your aspx.

Comment: Also check in the designer file that the event wireup is properly written for this or manually write it.

Comment: check this for event wireup https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/256290-Attaching-events-to-objects-created-in-code-behind

Comment: what calendar control do you use ?

Comment: I'm just using the standard calendar control. I'm just selecting it from my asp toolbox. I know that it's possible to use the ajax calendar extension but I'm going to try to get the standard calendar to work first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really consider using client side coding for this scenario. why do you have to go to the server to display a calender on click of a text box. All you have to do is write whatever is to be done in a javascript file and use it in client side. 
To do this, you can dothe following steps:

1. In your aspx page inside the `<head></head>` tag include

   `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="YourJavaScriptFile.js"></script>`
2. In your javascript file write a function to do whatever you want (display the calender).
3. call that function on any event (onclick) in you aspx.

I am not giving you the code as such because

- you might need a custom code for your scenario.
- you will have to do a bit more research.
- the basics of what is to be done has been covered.

Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The event is not firing because there is no server side onClick event for textbox! Try to wire the event up on the client side!

Comment: Why do you need an onClick event for a textbox exactly?

Comment: I want a calendar to appear when the textbox is clicked

Comment: I think you should really consider using JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY instead of posting back to the server to popup a calendar. Check out many examples that are already present online.

Comment: @roshambo To popup a calender, JS is fine. But according to the question: No, you do not need to code your own __doPostback call in the onclick of your client code. By adding the event like you did in the question, ASP.NET will paste the __doPostback call in the client onclick attribute of your input field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go for Ajaxtoolkit calendar control. Have a look at demo [here](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)